# Как подключить curl к cmake (archlinux)? Ошибка "неопределённая ссылка на «curl_easy_init»"

Tags: c++, curl, cmake, archlinux

При подключении curl через cmake вылезают в терминале такие строчки:

```
    main.cpp:(.text+0x9): неопределённая ссылка на «curl_easy_init»
    /usr/bin/ld: main.cpp:(.text+0x2a): неопределённая ссылка на «curl_easy_setopt»
    /usr/bin/ld: main.cpp:(.text+0x36): неопределённая ссылка на «curl_easy_perform»
```

На некоторых форумах говорилось, что нужно компилировать с флагом "-lcurl", но проблема в том что в cmake этот флаг и так прописан

CMakeList:

```
    cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.2.0)
    
    
    project(Scalpel)
    
    set(CURL_LIBRARY "-lcurl")
    find_package(CURL REQUIRED)
    
    add_executable(Scalpel main.cpp)
    
    if(LIBCURL_ENABLE)
        include_directories(${CURL_INCLUDE_DIR})
        target_link_libraries(Scalpel  ${CURL_LIBRARIES})
    endif()
    введите сюда код
```

В коде тоже ничего криминального нет:

```
    #define CURL_STATICLIB
    #include <iostream>
    #include <curl/curl.h>
    
    int main(){
        CURL* curl;
        curl = curl_easy_init();
        CURLcode reply;
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL ,"https://google.com");
        reply = curl_easy_perform(curl);
        curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: ¿Какие значения у переменных `LIBCURL_ENABLE` `CURL_LIBRARIES`? Лог сборки приводите.

Comment: Забавно. Cmake почему-то вообще ни слухом ни духом про LIBCURL_ENABLE. 
Я захотел его вывести с помощью message, но он начал ругаться. А как только я удалил упоминание этой переменной, то всё резко заработало. 
Спасибо вам за наводку.
И не подскажите пожалуйста, как можно выводить значение переменной через консоль?
Или это можно сделать только через message?

Comment: `message` - это и есть вывод через консоль. В VS обещают завести [отладчик для cmake](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/cmake-debugger-allows-you-to-debug-your-cmake-scripts-and-more/#:~:text=To%20initiate%20a%20CMake%20debugging,the%20%E2%80%9CProject%E2%80%9D%20dropdown%20menu.). Писать систему сборки на cmake - это боль.